# Maximum size limit of an Ear that can be deployed in WAS

Tags: java, deployment, server, websphere

I am trying to deploy an EAR of size 500 MB , where deployment is going for prolonged period of time without any error and getting cancelled also tried increasing the heap size doesn't help.
Can I get to know the maximum size of an ear allowed to deployed in WAS server
and also any other suggestions to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen applications over 1 GB deployed to WebSphere Application Server traditional.

Two things that can cause your deployment to take a long time.

1) The number of files in the application.  WebSphere Application Server traditional traverses the files inside WARs and makes a list of File objects. The more files you have in the application, the more memory is consumed and the longer it takes to deploy.   If you have large directories of files that are **not in Java EE defined directories**, consider removing those from the WAR and copying them to the *WAS_PROFILE_HOME*/installedApps/*APP_DIR*/*WAR_DIR*/ directory after deployment.  Alternatively, just add symlinks that point to the location of those directories after deployment.  If that helps, you will also want to look at this [article to improve your application start time.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PH09294)  Application start time suffers from the same problem.

2) If your application has a lot of JAR files and is at least at the Java EE 5 level, then annotation scanning will slow deployment.  Java EE 5 introduced annotations which requires the application server to scan the classes in JAR files for annotations.  WebSphere Application Server traditional provides a mechanism for you to specify which JARs should be scanned or which JARs should not be scanned.  This is discussed in this [article in the IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html).

Note also that the above only applies to WebSphere Application Server traditional.  WebSphere Liberty does not build a file list of files in the WARs, and it has a much faster annotation scanning engine.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion.

Ear of my application has less java and lib files ,but the size is because of the html files in the application. I have tried deploying the ear by removing some files of around(100MB) an deployed the 400 MB Ear which was successful and deployment completed in 15 mins through UCD. the issue of prolong deployment is only when I am trying to deploy the 500 MB where it doesn't show any errors in the system output logs. deployment alone is running for more than 9 hrs and getting cancelled .

Comment: 9 hrs down to 15 minutes is a pretty significant improvement.   Possibly there are more directories that can be removed, and the annotation scanning filters might help as well.  Note the actual size of the files does not matter as much as the number of files.  Each File object in the list can be over 400 bytes because it contains the complete path of the file. So an app with a ton of files can consume a lot of memory during deployment.

Comment: See this answer about performance ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526450/how-how-to-solve-slow-in-websphere-9-0-0-2/58544008#58544008 )  It can help determine whether the time is spent building a list of files or if the problem is annotation scanning or something else.

Comment: One more doubt on the same Issue, do we have to make any server configuration changes related to this EAR deployment issue.

Comment: If you are simply removing directories from the application before deployment and then adding the directories or symlinks to the application after deployment, then there is no server configuration change necessary.  To improve application start time then there are environment variables to set.  If using the most recent version of WAS, see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PH09294. If using an older version of WAS, see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM37942

Comment: If you are trying to reduce annotation scanning by using filtering, then you will need to either update the amm.filter.properties file, set environment variables, or update the MANIFEST.MF of the application.   For details, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html.